# Inner join in viewBag

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I try to return the following list to my view:

```
 var Things =  from a in db.Things
               where a.ID == id
               join b in db.IssueTypes on a.ID equals b.ID
               select a;

    List<Things> currentThings = Things.ToList();
        ViewBag.currentThing = currentThings;
```

Th view:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.currentThing)
{
<table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Title</td>
                    <td>@item.Title</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>@item.ID</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Description from Inner join:</td>
                    <td>@item.b.Description</td>
                </tr>
</table>
}
```

I try to display the row from the inner join as `@item.b.Description`. But this does not work. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: "But this does not work." In what way exactly? Do you get an error, does no data appear on the page? Also, can you show the controller method that your code is executing please? Might help give context to potential answers.

Comment: User a ViewModel instead of ViewBag

Comment: @JasonEvans the error:  ....does not contain a definition for 'b'

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee I totally agree. I use viewmodels all the time. Regards this question though, his code should work, so I'm interested to find out more about the OP's issue.

Comment: Looks like your LINQ query is incorrect, in that `b` has not been defined.

Comment: `select a;` means your selecting all the properties of `Things` (its not selecting any properties of `IssueTypes`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are only projecting `a` which means your query is returning only the properties of `db.Things`, to get the properties of `db.IssueTypes` as well you will have to project both like this:-

```
var Things =  from a in db.Things
               where a.ID == id
               join b in db.IssueTypes on a.ID equals b.ID
               select new { a, b };
```

Then, assign this directly to `ViewBag` like this:-

```
ViewBag.currentThing = Things;
```

Finally, you can use `b.Description` in your View.

Although, I would suggest you to create a `ViewModel` instead and create a strongly types View.

Comment: if I use @item.b.Description: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'b'

Comment: @JasonB - You sure you have included `new {a,b}`? I hope you have compiled the code.